# C# Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Character'

Tags: c#

The problem is that I keep getting this error

> Cannot convert from OmzetApplicatie.lib.Category to string

The error occurs on this line of code:

```
categories.Add(new Category(item));
```

Complete code:

```
List<string> categories;

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] categorynames = { "Vlees", "Snacks", "Drank", "Groenten en Fruit", "Droge voeding", "Sauzen", "Diepvries" };

    foreach (string item in categorynames)
    {
        categories.Add(new Category(item));
    }

    Product[][] products = {
            new Product[] { new Product("gehakt", 6.4M, 5.30M), new Product("hamburger", 9.0M, 6.25M), new Product("kip", 9.7M, 7.13M), new Product("biefstuk", 17.9M, 13.38M), new Product("preparé", 10.3M, 7.86M) },
            new Product[] { new Product("chips", 1.8M, 1.51M), new Product("nootjes", 7.00M, 5.83M), new Product("suikerwafels", 0.9M, 0.73M), new Product("snoep", 1.9M, 1.34M) },
            new Product[] { new Product("water", 0.3M, 0.23M), new Product("cola", 2.0M, 1.55M), new Product("ice-tea", 1.8M, 1.23M), new Product("fanta", 1.8M, 1.34M), new Product("sprite", 1.8M, 1.36M) },
            new Product[] { new Product("appels", 1.2M, 1.03M), new Product("komkommer", 0.4M, 0.36M), new Product("paprika", 2.4M, 2.05M), new Product("banaan", 1.4M, 1.15M), new Product("champignons", 0.8M, 0.63M) },
            new Product[] { new Product("spaghetti", 1.3M, 1.05M), new Product("rijst", 2.2M, 2.03M), new Product("hamburgerbroodjes", 2.4M, 2.17M), new Product("brood", 1.4M, 1.03M), new Product("macaroni", 0.3M, 0.26M) },
            new Product[] { new Product("ketchup", 2.7M, 2.27M), new Product("mayonaise", 1.7M, 1.12M), new Product("pesto", 0.8M, 0.63M), new Product("tomatensaus", 0.5M, 0.38M) },
            new Product[] { new Product("ijs", 1.7M, 1.34M), new Product("frieten", 1.7M, 1.62M), new Product("kroketten", 3.2M, 3.05M), new Product("frikandel", 1.9M, 1.62M), new Product("pizza", 2.3M, 2.16M) }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < products.Length; i++)
    {
        foreach (Product p in products[i])
        {
            categories[i].AddProduct(p);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my class from my class library

```cs
namespace OmzetApplicatie.lib
{
    public class Category
    {
        public string item;
        public string[] categorynames;

        public Category(string item)
        {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error you've listed in your title is not the same error that you've included in the question body. Please edit the question to make the two consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be

```cs
 List<Category> categories;
```

Comment: Looking at this now, this is kind of shamefull ahah

Answer (score 3):

If you change

```
List<string> categories;
```

to

```
List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
```

at least you will be able to compile.

Whether that is what you wanted remains to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write as below:

```
categories.Add(new Category(item).item);
```